# Why do I keep getting an attribute error in my XML document?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

Im new to XML and keep getting the error below:

Element 'topBilledActors' is based on a simple type definition. Attribute 'ids' is not defined in the schema instance namespace (xsi).

The code for my documents is below:

```
<!--lib.xsd-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns="http://www.superstarmovies.com/library" targetNamespace="http://www.superstarmovies.com/library">
<!--actorID-->
<xs:simpleType name="actorID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
        <xs:pattern value="a[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--actorIDREF-->
<xs:simpleType name="actorIDREF">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:IDREF">
        <xs:pattern value="a[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="actorIDREFlist">
    <xs:list itemType="actorIDREF"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--movieID-->
<xs:simpleType name="movieID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
        <xs:pattern value="m[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--movieIDREF-->
<xs:simpleType name="movieIDREF">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:IDREF">
        <xs:pattern value="m[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--rankType-->
<xs:simpleType name="rankType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--enumerated Yes/No-->
<xs:simpleType name="yes_no">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="yes"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="no"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--genreType-->
<xs:simpleType name="genreName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="action"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="comedy"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="drama"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="fantasy"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--roleType-->
<xs:complexType name="roleType">
        <xs:attribute name="character" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="movie" type="movieIDREF" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>


<!--catalog.xsd--> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:lib="http://www.superstarmovies.com/library" xmlns="http://www.superstarmovies.com/catalog" targetNamespace="http://www.superstarmovies.com/catalog">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.superstarmovies.com/library" schemaLocation="lib.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="catalog">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element ref="actor" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="movie" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<!--actor type-->
<xs:element name="actor">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="date"/>
            <xs:element ref="birthplace"/>
            <xs:element ref="role"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="actor" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="oscarWinner" use="optional" default="no"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="birthplace" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
<xs:element name="role" type="lib:roleType"/>
<xs:attribute name="actor" type="lib:actorID"/>
<xs:attribute name="oscarWinner" type="lib:yes_no"/>
<!--movie type-->
<xs:element name="movie">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="title"/>
            <xs:element ref="year"/>
            <xs:element ref="length"/>
            <xs:element ref="topBilledActors"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="genre" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="earningsRank" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="year" type="xs:gYear"/>
<xs:element name="length" type="xs:time"/>
<xs:element name="topBilledActors" type="lib:actorIDREFlist"/>
<xs:attribute name="id" type="lib:movieID"/>
<xs:attribute name="genre" type="lib:genreName"/>
<xs:attribute name="earningsRank" type="lib:rankType"/>
</xs:schema>


<!--catalog.xml-->
<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.superstarmovies.com/catalog file:///C:/Users/akhanijow/Desktop/Assignment%201%20COMP/catalog.xsd" xmlns="http://www.superstarmovies.com/catalog">
<movie id="m2001-012" genre="drama">
    <title>Monster&apos;s Ball</title>
    <year>2001</year>
    <length>01:51:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0100 a0102"/>
</movie>
<actor id="a0100" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Halle Berry</name>
    <date>1966-08-14</date>
    <birthplace>Cleveland, OH</birthplace>
    <role character="Leticia Musgrove" movie="m2001-012"/>
    <role character="Storm" movie="m2000-035"/>
</actor>
<actor id="a0102" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Billy Bob Thornton</name>
    <role character="Hank Grotowski" movie="m2001-012"/>
</actor>
<movie id="m2000-035" genre="fantasy">
    <title>X-Men</title>
    <year>2000</year>
    <length>01:44:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0100 a0103"/>
</movie>
<actor id="a0103" oscarWinner="no">
    <name>Ian McKellen</name>
    <role character="Magneto" movie="m2000-035"/>
    <role character="Gandolf" movie="m2001-105"/>
    <role character="Gandolf" movie="m2003-107"/>
</actor>
<movie id="m2001-105" genre="action" earningsRank="17">
    <title>Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring</title>
    <year>2001</year>
    <length>02:58:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0103"/>
</movie>
<movie id="m2003-107" genre="action" earningsRank="8">
    <title>Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King</title>
    <year>2003</year>
    <length>03:21:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0103"/>
</movie>
<actor id="a0101" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Tom Hanks</name>
    <date>1956-07-09</date>
    <birthplace>Concord, CA</birthplace>
    <role character="Captain John H. Miller" movie="m1998-102"/>
    <role character="Forrest Gump" movie="m1994-103"/>
    <role character="Andrew Beckett" movie="m1993-104"/>
</actor>
<movie id="m1998-102" genre="action" earningsRank="50">
    <title>Saving Private Ryan</title>
    <year>1998</year>
    <length>02:50:00 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0101 a0104"/>
</movie>
<actor id="a0104" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Matt Damon</name>
    <date>1970-10-08</date>
    <birthplace>Cambridge, MA</birthplace>
    <role character="Private James Francis Ryan" movie="m1998-102"/>
</actor>
<movie id="m1994-103" genre="comedy" earningsRank="14">
    <title>Forrest Gump</title>
    <year>1994</year>
    <length>02:22:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0101 a0105 a0106"/>
</movie>
<actor id="a0105" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Sally Field</name>
    <birthplace>Pasadena, CA</birthplace>
    <role character="Mrs. Gump" movie="m1994-103"/>
</actor>
<actor id="a0106">
    <name>Gary Sinise</name>
    <role character="Lt. Dan Taylor" movie="m1994-103"/>
    <role character="Ken Mattingly" movie="m1995-106"/>
</actor>
<movie id="m1993-104" genre="drama">
    <title>Philadelphia</title>
    <year>1993</year>
    <length>02:05:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0101 a0107"/>
</movie>
<movie id="m1995-106" genre="drama">
    <title>Apollo 13</title>
    <year>1995</year>
    <length>02:20:00</length>
    <topBilledActors ids="a0101 a0106"/>
</movie>
<actor id="a0107" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Denzel Washington</name>
    <role character="Joe Miller" movie="m1993-104"/>
</actor>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your XML:

```
<topBilledActors ids="a0100 a0102"/>
```

But according to your schema definition `topBilledActors` is type of `actorIDREFlist` and does not define an attribute call `ids`.

You can delete the `ids` attribute in your XML, or change the schema definition to include that attribute.

Comment: Hi, I have tried doing that just now and am still getting errors. The catalog.xml file was given with the     'ids'    attribute. What would I need to change in the schema to allow the     'ids'    attribute?

Sorry, I've been looking at this forever and am stuck. Thanks!